# Uninstall ASP.NET from IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, uninstall

Since we develop using ColdFusion/PHP, we don't need ASP.net to be enabled.

So, how can I remove ASP support from my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\aspnet_regiis.exe -ua
```